# Running arbitrary Python code from Python and preserving return values

Tags: python, python-embedding

I am attempting to write an API in Python that will allow me to run arbitrary Python code. In particular, I would like to be able to call any function through the API and have the return value passed back to me. The use case is that I have a Python library from which I would like to call functions from Java. Jython only supports Python 2 and I would prefer not embed Python in C/C++ embedded in Java.

My first instinct is to use exec(), but exec() does not support returning values. E.g,
`exec('10+20')` returns `None`. Is there a more elegant way to do this than writing the output to a variable within the exec() call? e.g. `exec('a=10+20')`

Comment: `compile()` in eval mode maybe?

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is below, and it even seems to work, which is nice.

```
import ast

def execute_with_return(code: str):
    tree = ast.parse(code)
    return_expr = None
    if type(tree.body[-1]) == ast.Expr:
        return_expr = tree.body[-1]
        tree.body = tree.body[:-1]
    exec(ast.unparse(tree))
    if return_expr:
        return eval(ast.unparse(return_expr))
```